# Drop duplicates, keep most recent date in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, duplicates

I have a Pandas dataframe containing two columns: a datetime column, and a column of integers representing station IDs. I need a new dataframe with the following modifications:

For each set of duplicate `STATION_ID` values, keep the row with the most recent entry for `DATE_CHANGED`. If the duplicate entries for the `STATION_ID` all contain the same `DATE_CHANGED` then drop the duplicates and retain a single row for the `STATION_ID`. If there are no duplicates for the `STATION_ID` value, simply retain the row.

Dataframe (sorted by `STATION_ID`):

```
              DATE_CHANGED  STATION_ID
0      2006-06-07 06:00:00           1
1      2000-09-26 06:00:00           1
2      2000-09-26 06:00:00           1
3      2000-09-26 06:00:00           1
4      2001-06-06 06:00:00           2
5      2005-07-29 06:00:00           2
6      2005-07-29 06:00:00           2
7      2001-06-06 06:00:00           2
8      2001-06-08 06:00:00           4
9      2003-11-25 07:00:00           4
10     2001-06-12 06:00:00           7
11     2001-06-04 06:00:00           8
12     2017-04-03 18:36:16           8
13     2017-04-03 18:36:16           8
14     2017-04-03 18:36:16           8
15     2001-06-04 06:00:00           8
16     2001-06-08 06:00:00          10
17     2001-06-08 06:00:00          10
18     2001-06-08 06:00:00          11
19     2001-06-08 06:00:00          11
20     2001-06-08 06:00:00          12
21     2001-06-08 06:00:00          12
22     2001-06-08 06:00:00          13
23     2001-06-08 06:00:00          13
24     2001-06-08 06:00:00          14
25     2001-06-08 06:00:00          14
26     2001-06-08 06:00:00          15
27     2017-08-07 17:48:25          15
28     2001-06-08 06:00:00          15
29     2017-08-07 17:48:25          15
...                    ...         ...
157066 2018-08-06 14:11:28       71655
157067 2018-08-06 14:11:28       71656
157068 2018-08-06 14:11:28       71656
157069 2018-09-11 21:45:05       71664
157070 2018-09-11 21:45:05       71664
157071 2018-09-11 21:45:05       71664
157072 2018-09-11 21:41:04       71664
157073 2018-08-09 15:22:07       71720
157074 2018-08-09 15:22:07       71720
157075 2018-08-09 15:22:07       71720
157076 2018-08-23 12:43:12       71899
157077 2018-08-23 12:43:12       71899
157078 2018-08-23 12:43:12       71899
157079 2018-09-08 20:21:43       71969
157080 2018-09-08 20:21:43       71969
157081 2018-09-08 20:21:43       71969
157082 2018-09-08 20:21:43       71984
157083 2018-09-08 20:21:43       71984
157084 2018-09-08 20:21:43       71984
157085 2018-09-05 18:46:18       71985
157086 2018-09-05 18:46:18       71985
157087 2018-09-05 18:46:18       71985
157088 2018-09-08 20:21:44       71990
157089 2018-09-08 20:21:44       71990
157090 2018-09-08 20:21:44       71990
157091 2018-09-08 20:21:43       72003
157092 2018-09-08 20:21:43       72003
157093 2018-09-08 20:21:43       72003
157094 2018-09-10 17:06:18       72024
157095 2018-09-10 17:15:05       72024

[157096 rows x 2 columns]
```

`DATE_CHANGED` is `dtype: datetime64[ns]`

`STATION_ID` is `dtype: int64`

pandas==0.23.4

python==2.7.15

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try:

```
df.sort_values('DATE_CHANGED').drop_duplicates('STATION_ID',keep='last')
```

Comment: What if one more column 'Status' is there, Status has value like Success and fail. I want to drop duplicates based in condition if STATION_ID has success and Fail both, we will take success and drop fail row. How we can achieve this?

Comment: @Taylor you've probably already worked this out, but you should simply be able to add the `Status` column to the `.sort_values()` parameters and define the asc/desc naure of the sort, as `fail` would precede `success` i.e. `df.sort_values(['DATE_CHANGED', 'Status'], ascending = [True, False])`

Comment: df = df.sort_values('DATE_CHANGED').drop_duplicates('STATION_ID',keep='last')

Answer (score 0):

If `DATE_CHANGED` is dtype `datetime64` (as it is in the OP), `groupby.max` can be used as well because the most recent date has the highest value.

```py
df['DATE_CHANGED'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_CHANGED'])
df.groupby('STATION_ID', as_index=False)['DATE_CHANGED'].max()
```

If the values are sorted by `DATE_CHANGED`, then `groupby.tail` may be used as well.

```py
df = df.sort_values(by='DATE_CHANGED')
df.groupby('STATION_ID', as_index=False).tail(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a function to reuse it. All you need is to specify the `date column` and the `column to filter`:

```
def remove_duplicate_records(input_df: pd.DataFrame, dt_info: str, col_to_filter: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Removes duplicated records by checking with dt_info 
    and then it picks the row with latest date

    :param: df_input is the input dataframe that contains unfiltered data
    :param: dt_info is the date column which will be used to sort the rows
    :param: col_to_filter is the column/s whose duplicated rows will be 
     discarded and latest row will be preserved
    :return: filtered dataframe with duplicated row removed
    """
    # sort the dataframe according to date
    df_sorted_by_dt = input_df.sort_values(dt_info)
    # drop duplicated rows and keep the last since last is the latest
    df_filtered_latest = df_sorted_by_dt.drop_duplicates([col_to_filter], keep='last')
    # clear variable that are not needed
    del df_sorted_by_dt
    return df_filtered_latest
```

Then call the above function:

```
# df = pd.read_csv("input_path.csv")
# input data is df 
date_column = "DATE_CHANGED"
col_to_filter = "STATION_ID"
filtered_df = remove_duplicate_records(df, date_column, col_to_filter)
```